# Replace value in a vector

Tags: c++, stl

I want to add the closing parenthesis where the string starts with `[[`

I tried using `find_if`, `replace_if` but it turns out that something isn't right

```
std::vector<std::string> vector(3);
```

contains:

```
    0: text
    1: [[text
    2: text
```

What I want:

```
    0: text
    1: [[text]]
    2: text
```

Could you help with algorithm explanation?

Comment: Those are brackets, not parenthesis.

Comment: What's your code? What didn't work? Did you try debugging?

Comment: @Ilya Kogan, Andrey, I tried to use a predicate like: `[](std::string str) {
     return str.find("[[") != string::npos ? true : false;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
for (std::string & s : vector)
{
    if (s.size() > 1 && s[0] == '[' && s[1] == '[')
        s += "]]";
}
```

If you want to check for already existing brackets, add some more checks.

Answer (score 3):

How about a little [`for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) action?

```
void check_and_replace(std::string& str) {
    if (str.length() >= 2) {
        if (str[0] == '[' && str[1] == '[')
            str += "]]";
    }
}

for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), check_and_replace);
```

Comment: Passing `str` by value is a bad idea, because `str += "]]";` is only changing a local copy.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Spending too much time in python and C# where that wouldn't have mattered. I believe my edit corrects this?

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution:

```
int main()
{ 
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("text");
    v.push_back("[[text");
    v.push_back("text");

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i].find("[[") == 0)
        {
            v[i].append("]]");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that's easy. There's no `find_if`/`replace_if` variant for mutating multiple values, but there's `copy_if`.

So, given our vector,

```
std::vector<std::string> v = { "text", "[[text", "text" };
```

we can isolate all the elements we want to change:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> v2;
std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), [](std::string const& s) { return s.compare(0, 2, "[[") == 0 && (s.size() < 2 || s.compare(s.size() - 2, 2, "]]")); } );
```

and then simply transform each of them into the desired output value:

```
std::for_each(v2.begin(), v2.end(), [](std::string& x) { return x += "]]"; });
```

Thanks to the standard library algorithms, we can easily check our work too:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::string const& x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; });
```

Just make sure to include all the required headers.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 0):

find_if will work if you use a correct predictor function. What predictor are you using?

try this:

```
 boolean containsBrackets( string s )
 {
     s.contains("[[");
 }
```